# Creating a graph similar to Battery usage in Gingerbread

Tags: android, graph, power-management

I just wanted to create a trend in my activity that would look like the Gingerbread battery one (see picture above)

I am looking deeply in the [Android git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java;h=ea28c595c8bfbcfb229ccf0088465aadef254e39;hb=HEAD) and found what seem to be the correct activity

Unfortunately, I cannot find something related to canvas or drawing and how I can use this code to create my own trend.

If someone could point me where I could find the drawing process or point me another open source sample with a trend activity, would be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the graphing is handled by [BatteryHistoryChart.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/BatteryHistoryChart.java;h=23107da8f4fa33d4f2aa25c65a40c89f0859d9a8;hb=HEAD).

Comment: @user3233280 check this link:https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/BatteryHistoryChart.java

Comment: @Erich Douglass i m using this link for graph but GraphViewSeries class is not present in this library how can i resolve ?https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView